# How to add color to numbers in the Listings package?

Tags: listings, lyx

I am using the Listings package in Lyx. I can change the color of whatever word I want using `\lstset{emph={word}}` and `\lstset{emphstyle={\color{green}}}`. However this does not work with numbers.

`\lstset{emph={2}}` and `\lstset{emphstyle={\color{green}}}` doesn't color every number '2' green.

Can you add color to numbers?

Minimal working example:

```
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset listings
lstparams "emph={WORD, 0},emphstyle={\color{green}}"
inline false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

This is some code
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

This WORD is green
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

This 0 is not green
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Hi, please add Your minimal working example, couse it's very hard to tell You smt without any Your own example

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `numberstyle` key

A minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\lstset{numbers=left, numbersep=10pt, numberstyle=\ttfamily\tiny\color{red}}
\begin{lstlisting}
foo
bar
baz
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

You may refer to the very comprehensive [`listings` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) for further information.

Comment: The numbers I was referring to are not the ones on the side that indicate the line number. What I meant is that if instead of having the word "foo" at the start I have the number "5", how can I change its format.

Comment: If I wanted to change the font color of "foo" I could use ```\lstset{emph={foo}}``` and ```\lstset{emphstyle={\color{green}}}```. However, this only works for words, not numbers

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway :)